# Programing button in mac objective-c

Tags: objective-c, button

i have some code here:

```
-(void)handleButton {
    NSLog(@"hello");
}
```

and i wanted to connect that function to occur when i press a button that is named, `theButton`
I know that you can link things in the interface programer but that does not let me use functions, so how would i do this so i can use functions???

i've tried to use codes like this one:

```
[theButton setTarget:self];
[theButton setAction:@selector(handleButton:)];
```

to set the button to call that function but when i do it gives me an error that `theButton` is not declared, i know this is probably dumb and has a simple answer but i cant figure it out.

Comment: Can we see some more code? where did you declare theButton ?

Comment: i didn't think that i needed too, since it is in the interface... i don't know how to i thought since i named the button that was the declaration, i'm new to objective c.

Comment: Did you include the header in the .m file?

Comment: yes but i did't put anything special in the .h file other than the standard stuff that comes with an objective-c app template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method takes no argument, so its selector would be specified as `@selector(handleButton)`. However, this is incorrect. An action should take a single argument, the ID of the sender:

```
-(IBAction)handleButton:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"hello");
}
```

As for interface builder, it does let you set functions as actions; that's the whole point. Without the `IBAction`, interface builder doesn't know that the method is supposed to be an action, so it won't present it as an option.

Both of these problems are good illustrations of why you should use code generators, as XCode would have generated the proper signature for you.

Comment: but how would i declare it so i can add the button to the delegates of the app?